# Text justify center in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, justify

In my SSRS report, I am getting texts to fill a table from a dataset (SQL Query).

There is a particular line of text from the query that I'd like to be displayed center (i.e. justify center).

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show the result which you want .Using `toolbox`  you can align the text

Comment: Basically the whole report's text comes from dataset (title header + body) as I am just printing out the report based on a particular table in SQL). I want the title to be centered and the rest to be 'normal'. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Basically certain texts/lines need to be aligned center. Can I justify center programatically?

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify the row in some way but it can be done because everything in Reporting Services is an expression. So let's say you want the first row to be centered and bold. You would enter an expression for the `TextAlign` property like:

```
=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) = 1, "Center", "Left")
```

and for the `Font`-`FontWeight` property like:

```
=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) = 1, "Bold", "Normal")
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the object or cell you want the text justification to apply to, then either:

- click the "Center" button the toolbar (shown as a image of stacked horizontal lines, in the same toolbar as the font settings)
- click on the Properties window and edit the TextAlign property, setting it to "Center"

Comment: I know about this center button. But my text comes from SQL dataset, and there is only ONE line from the text that I want to be centered! Is that possible?

Comment: I guess what I mean am I able to programmatically set certain texts to be aligned center?

Comment: You set the text alignment on the container, not on the text itself, so if you can put the line you want centered in its own textbox or table cell then you can use an expression to set the TextAlign property. Another alternative is to use multiple Placeholders in the same container, as you can set the text properties differently for each placeholder. However both these approaches require the text to be center aligned to be be separated from the rest of the text. There isn't a way to apply different formatting to part of a string of text that is all in the same container.